# QR Login via Database using async task in android

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app for QR authentication of an employee,the code below works but it takes time to open the next activity,so i want to put my code in an async task, i don't understand how async task works(tried a lot  but didn't understand),it would be really helpful if someone can put my code in the async task.

**LOGIN ACTIVITY CODE**

```
public class QrLogin extends ActionBarActivity {
    String contents=""; 
 ConnectionClass connectionClass  = new ConnectionClass();;
Connection con = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//OPEN BARCODE SCANNER APP
         Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
         intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");//for Qr code, its "QR_CODE_MODE" instead of "PRODUCT_MODE"
         intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
         intent.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "EMPLOYEEE");//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
         startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }


    //authenticating user via sql server
    public void BgTask()
    {
     Boolean isSuccess = true;

        if(isSuccess) //if authentication fails
        {
             Intent i = new Intent(this,InvalidLogin_screen.class);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
             finish();
             }

             else   {
                 Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR IN APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                       finish();
             }

        try {

              con = connectionClass.CONN();

             if (con == null) {
                 Toast x = Toast.makeText(this, "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    x.show();
                       finish();
             } 
             else
             {
             String query = "select * from pitable where UserID='" +contents  + "'";
             Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);



             while(rs.next())
             {



                  if(contents.equals(rs.next()))
                  {
                      //Valid Login
                  }

                  else
                  {
                //   Invalid Login
                     isSuccess=true;
                  }

                //if authentication passes
                     Intent n = new Intent(this, WelcomeScreen.class);
                    n.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                     startActivity(n);
             }
             }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Log.e("Eception", ex.getMessage());
                 ex.printStackTrace();

                   Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Exceptions!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    finish();
                 }

         finally{

             try{
                 if(con!= null && !con.isClosed()){
                     con.close();
                 }
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("Connection", e.getMessage());
             }
         }
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

          if (requestCode == 0) {
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");//result of the QRcode scan

                 BgTask();
                }

               else 
               { 
                   Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR IN SCANNING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                finish();

               }
       }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a a "do me stuff for free" kind of site, you should at least try doing it yourself and if it doesn't work we might help you out.

Comment: sorry,I'm just a beginner in android development,I anyway tried doing it.I still face an issue.A white blank screen appears before i switch to the next activity.HELP!  I've linked my code here->
      [link](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5648)